# How to subtract time from current time in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

```
$clock_in = Carbon::createFromFormat('g:i A', Input::get('clock_in'))->timezone('UTC');
$clock_out = Carbon::createFromFormat('g:i A', Input::get('clock_out'))->timezone('UTC');

$attendance->clock_in = $clock_in->format('H:i:s');
$attendance->clock_out = $clock_out->format('H:i:s');
```

In this code I have clockIn and clockOut which get current time. Now, I want to subtract `5 hour :30 min` from both i.e. clockIn and clockout. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: First try to convert the given time into epoch time and then substract the epoch value

Comment: Actually I am new in laravel So, I don't have  any idea about epoch @farooq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`5 hr 30 min` is equals to `5*3600+30*60 seconds`,

So you can use `subSeconds` look like this:

```php
$sec = 5*3600+30*60;
$attendance->clock_in = $clock_in->subSeconds($sec)->format('H:i:s');
$attendance->clock_out = $clock_out->subSeconds($sec)->format('H:i:s');
```

Or you can use `subMinutes`:

```php
$min = 5*60+30;
$attendance->clock_in = $clock_in->subMinutes($min)->format('H:i:s');
$attendance->clock_out = $clock_out->subMinutes($min)->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: Actually I want to subtract 5 hr 30 min from current time @TsaiKoga